# React Hooks: How to setState inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch data from firebase and set the retrieved data to my state using the useState hook. I know my API call is working because I can log the data from firebase, yet its not ending up in my state when I use setState(), for some reason I end up with just an empty array in state. What am I missing?

```
const Collection = () => {
  const [ dreams, setDreams ] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const retrieveCollection = (userId) => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('Dreams')
        .where('user', '==', userId)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          let newDreams = snapshot.docChanges()
          newDreams.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.doc.data())
            setDreams([...dreams, doc.doc.data()])
            console.log(dreams)
          })
        })
    }
    retrieveCollection('N25c9lKITZQ7JtPEZSrMX6uC7Ot2')
  }, [])
```

Comment: what do you see in `console.log(dreams)`?

Comment: i was seeing an empty array, @Boy With Silver Wings solution below solved it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`useState` much like it's counterpart `setState` returns an asynchronous function to set the state. So logging dreams just below the `setDreams` call isn't going to give you any results. Instead you can log inside outside the `useEffect` to see the state.

But `setDreams` being async has another disadvantage in your case, the loop doesn't set `dreams` quick enough for you to be able to spread it, you might be loosing updates in between, you can fix this using the functional `setDreams`.

```
setDreams(prevDreams => [...prevDreams, doc.doc.data()])
```

Or better still, you can save up all your data and setState at the very end.

```
const newDreamsState = newDreams.map(
  return doc.doc.data();
});
setDreams(newDreamsState);
```

Comment: Great to know . `setSomething(prevSomething => prevSomething.concat([x]))` works while `something.push(x); setSomething([...something]);` doesn't

Comment: (within a useEffect)